# git rollback use case

Tags: git, rollback

I'm new to git.

I implemented a feature in `A way`.
I want to try implementing the same feature in `B way`.

Then I'll probably need some time to evaluate whether the `B way` was a good idea.
While evaluating it, I'll modify `other parts` of program.

Suppose, I decide `B was bad and A was better`, and wanted to come back to `A way`.
But I'd like to keep the modification to the `other parts` of the program.

Can this be done in git?

-EDIT-
I'm adding pics to better explain what I'm trying to accomplish

Currently, I'm at the end of a_way(finished implementing A), except I don't know where X is..

```
                [a_way]
 o---X---a---a---a
```

I wanna try b_way.
Start from where I am, remove(or comment out) code related to a_way, and implement b_way

```
   o---X---a---a---a
                    \
                     remove a_way--implement b_way
```

I'll need some time to evaluate the effectiveness of b_way, and will keep developing other features.

```
   o---X---a---a---a
                    \
                     remove a_way--implement b_way--develop new features
```

Now I figure a_way was better than b_way and decide to go back to a_way.

```
   o---X---a---a---a--------------------------------new features(I wanna end up here)
                    \
                     remove a_way--implement b_way--new features
```

Comment: The details depend on whether you did ``A`` and ``B`` in separate branches

Comment: I'm already at the end of A.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like you're after rebasing.

One way to do this in git is to have two branches `a_way` and `b_way`.

When you've finshed building the two ways you'll have a tree that looks like this

```
                [a_way]
 o---X---a---a---a
      \
        -b---b---b
                 [b_way]
```

Where `a` are the commits to implement A way, and `b` are the commmits to implement B.

Now assuming you change your branch name to `develop` once a_way is complete and hack away for a while. You tree will look like this:

```
              [a_way]
 o---X---a---a---a---d1---d2---d3---d4 [develop]
      \
        -b---b---b
                 [b_way]
```

Now you decide you want to get rid of `a_way` and switch to `b_way` instead.

```
git rebase --onto b_way a_way develop
```

will give me:

```
              [a_way]
 o---X---a---a---a
      \
        -b---b---b---d1'---d2'---d3'---d4' [develop]
                 [b_way]
```

Note: If develop has merges in it, this will flatten out the merges, I suspect theres a way to preserve the merges, but I have not needed it yet. It will also cause the commit IDs to change, which could cause problems if there are other people basing work off of that.

*ADDENDUM*

It sounds like your repository looks like this:

```
                             [a_way]
 o---X             a---a---a
      \           /
        -b---b---b---d1---d2---d3---d4 [develop]
               [b_way]
```

If you want it to end up like this:

```
                             [a_way]
 o---X             a---a---a
      \           /         \
        b---b---b           d1'---d2'---d3'---d4' [develop]
               [b_way]
```

Then the command you'd issue is

```
 git rebase --onto a_way b_way develop
```

Or in this case it can be simplified to

```
git checkout develop
git rebase a_way
```

*ADDENDUM*

So your respository actually looks like this:

```
 o---X---a---a---a [a_way]
                  \
                    da---da---da---b---b---b---f---f---f [develop]
                            [remove_a]   [b_way]
```

And you want to get to

```
   o---X---a---a---a---f---f---f [develop]
                    \
                     da---da---da---b---b---b
```

The command to do this is

```
git rebase --onto a_way b_way develop
```

If you dont have branches at the required places you can use the commit SHAs.

```
git rebase --onto  a_way
```

Comment: nice pictorial description.(although A&B are switched from my question) I get the concept. Let me make one thing clear.  I'm on the master branch.(at the end of b_way in your answer). Now I'm creating A branch for a_way and develop. So a_way will branch out at the end of b_way(as opposed to branching out from common parent). I think this affects the overall strategy I can take?  Second question: [a_way] and [develop] in your second picture seems to be associated with specific nodes. Am I interpreting it correctly? [branch_name] can be associated with the specific node in git history?

Comment: @Eugene In git a branch is just a reference to the commit which is currently the latest commit on that branch. A branch name can thus always be resolved to a commit (but not necessarily the same one over time), but you cannot determine on which branch a commit originated.

Comment: What I'm trying to show in the change from `d1` to `d1'` is that the commits SHA will change on rebase, but the content of each commit should essentially stay the same (other than conflicts and detection of already applied changes).

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify the question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have `A` and `B` in separate branches, lets say `A` and `B`. Once you decide you want to keep `A` you'll merge it back into the development branch (usually `master`, or `develop`).

```
git checkout master
git merge A
```

And you get rid of both branches `A` and `B`

```
git branch -d `A`
git branch -D `B`
```

Because `B` is not merged into your development branch and the changes will get lost you have to force the deletion with the uppercase `D`.

And `other parts`? They are probably already in our development branch (as said `master`, or `develop`, or something) and remain there even after you merge `A` into.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever commited it?
If not , `git stash` could reveal what you have done after last commit,and then you could try another way. when you wanna the change , just use `git stash apply`

It's another way different from above, but I do think use branch is much better, since you are new to git, it's very important for you to know this :-)